# Construtores no PHP 7

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, construtor

Estava testando uma classe no PHP 7, e reparei que o construtor não funciona mais quando é criado a partir do nome da classe, funcionando somente quando é criado com o nome `__construct`.

Exemplo:

```
<?php

// Assim funciona:
class MinhaClasse {
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'Ok!';
    }
}

// Assim não:
class MinhaClasse {
    public function MinhaClasse() {
        echo 'Ok!';
    }
}
```

Houve alguma mudança? E se teve, por quê?

Comment: Se não me engano, parece ter uma pergunta e ou uma resposta falando sobre o assunto! Não tenho certeza, mas vou ver se consigo encontrar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu não poderia afirmar o motivo que houve a mudança, posso dizer algumas coisas que sei sobre PHP que pode dar indícios.

Todos sabemos, e alguns não aceitam, que o processo de desenvolvimento do PHP é caótico, em geral realizado por programadores até bons, mas que não sabem criar uma linguagem. Não ajuda o fato que [PHP já foi criada de forma sem muito entendimento de como uma linguagem funciona](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Rasmus_Lerdorf).

Acredito que um dia alguém achou que seria melhor ter um método com nome neutro porque se renomeasse a classe, economizaria digitação para mudar o construtor, então resolveram trocar a forma original que era boa e não criava problemas para ninguém por uma nova forma que só trouxe uma vantagem pontual e questionável.

Na verdade me parece um motivo muito errado. Você não deve renomear suas classes, isto causa muito impacto em um sistema grande. E se renomear, o menor dos seus problemas será também renomear o construtor dentro da classe (terá que renomear em toda aplicação que chama esta classe).

Talvez não seja tão difícil assim mudar tudo na aplicação. Mas se isso for verdade, por que está usando OOP? Em coisas simples OOP não traz vantagens, então nada disso deveria ser discutido.

PHP tem outras deficiências que prejudicam o desenvolvimento de aplicações grandes que são as que precisam de OOP.

Também diz-se que seria para poder usar o nome da classe como método comum. Não sei que vantagem isso dá. Sei que gera confusão porque o construtor será chamado com o nome da classe, então teria construtor e método comum com o mesmo nome. Só lambança.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Se as pessoas entendessem que o PHP é uma linguagem de alma caseira que copiou coisas de linguagens mais sérias, saberiam melhor lidar com ela (um jeito alternativo de me referir ao desenvolvimento caótico). É por isso que a grande minoria que realmente programa bem em PHP costuma ser quem já tem experiência em outras linguagens. O interessante é que os programadores da "velha guarda" (que usavam PHP como PHP) não tem tantos problemas como os da pergunta, justamente pelo fato de não dependerem do "academicismo" artificial da linguagem.

Answer (score 7):

Essa foi uma mudança que aconteceu no PHP 7.
Você pode mais ler sobre isso na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.decon.php).

---

#### *Teve alguma mudança?*

De acordo com a documentação citada acima:

> Construtores no estilo antigo se tornaram OBSOLETOS no PHP 7.0, e serão removidos em uma versão futura.

---

#### *Se teve, por quê?*

A documentação não cita isso explicitamente, mas há um trecho de código:

> ```
> <?php
> namespace Foo;
> class Bar {
>     public function Bar() {
>         // tratado como construtor no PHP 5.3.0-5.3.2
>         // tratado como método comum a partir do PHP 5.3.3
>     }
> }
> ```

Que indica que provavelmente a razão para tal mudança foi dar a possibilidade de criar métodos comuns com o nome da classe, o que não era possível quando os contrutores eram definidos a partir do nome da classe.

Comment: Acho que a intenção da pergunta foi enriquecer o conteúdo da rede SOPT trazendo informações relevantes para cá. Claro que a resposta pode estar descrita no link, mas mesmo assim seria mais interessante uma resposta um pouco mais esclarecedora aqui.

Comment: Tudo o que foi perguntado está na documentação, portanto não vi razão para citar o que está escrito na documentação, bastando apenas citar o link para tal.

Comment: Eu juro que percorri o link, e não consegui encontrar o ponto chave da pergunta, **por quê ?**

Comment: Provavelmente por falta de atenção. Para justificar, tive que editar a mensagem acima, tendo em vista que não há tamanho o suficiente para isso no campo dos comentários. ^-^

Comment: @lffg Não é assim que funciona o SOpt. Se fosse só para responder com links, acredito que não teria o porque de ter o SOpt. A sua resposta deve responder a pergunta, e os links são para complementar caso a pessoa queria ver.

Comment: Não concordo com a sua afirmação. Acho que a minha resposta foi clara e coesa em relação à pergunta. Mas cada um com a sua opinião. A vida segue.

Comment: Eu juro que também li, achei isso "Construtores no estilo antigo se tornaram OBSOLETOS no PHP 7.0, e serão removidos em uma versão futura." mas quem me diz que "Construtores no estilo antigo" é referente a outra forma !? Aí tenho que pesquisar no link da documentação, e pesquisar novamente para saber a fundo para ter certeza. Se não tem paciência para ajudar, enriquecer o conteúdo, então não precisa responder colega.

Comment: Agora com a sua edição, sua resposta ficou ótima. É assim que tem que ser.

Comment: Resposta editada, meu negativo foi retirado :) +1